# How to execute a process on remote machine (linux) without ssh?

Tags: linux, process, ssh

How can I execute a process in the remote machine running linux without ssh.Since the machine is scheduled to pxe boot periodically, ssh key will be changed and executing process through a script using ssh is ruled out.
Any idea on how it can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate as to why you ruled out ssh.

Comment: Would this be better answered if migrated to ServerFault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only problem with ssh is that you can't use key-based authentication, you don't have to rule out ssh entirely, you just have to automate a password-based authentication.

[This project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/) looks like it might be a good solution.

This should be more secure than http or telnet, as long as you keep your password and any files that contain it well guarded (which you would have to do with keys anyways).

Comment: Thanks a lot.This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via http, but I think this way is not safe.

For example, you can write a php script

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1')
    system("./yourPrograme");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)? It's not as secure as SSH though.